# ESXi Host Disk space

Tags: debian, virtualization, web-server, vmware-esxi

We've got an ESXi host, with 2x500gb raid 1 -> 500gb space. Currently there are 2 guest systems running:

bs: 28gb root partition, 102gb Data partition (independent, isn't included in snapshots)
t3: 69gb root partition, 131gb Data partition (also independent)

free space: 122gb

We did set up another guest(23gb root, 97gb Data(independent) -> 2gb free space), and made a snapshot of the t3 host. Then after some time, we tried to reboot it(t3). We found out, that there wasn't enough space for the host system. Now the big question is, how much does it need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much it needs depends on the snapshot deltas. I.e. how much the virtual machine changes from the time you took the snapshot and for how long you want to keep the snapshot.
Can be anywhere from 1% of the VMDK size to several hundred percent of the size.

Comment: why several 100 percents? Shouldnt be the max size the size of the snapshoted Disk?

Comment: well, Im going to leave 75 gig free, should be enough